# How to connect stardog studio with stardog server that has security disabled?

Tags: stardog

I am running stardog on the default port 5280 and i have successfully used stardog studio in the default configuration. To properly use stardog in my intranet i had to switch off security with

```bash
./stardog-server.sh start --disable-security
```

and now i can't find a way to create a connection from stardog studio
[image: Screen Shot 1]
since an empty username/password doesn't seem to be accepted.
[image: Screen Shot 2]

**How can i use stardog studio with a server that has the security disabled?**

Comment: The default username/password combo should be admin/admin.  Try putting those in. If you open your browser's developer tools and look at the console responses, what error messages do you see?  I'm assuming either a credential/unauthorized, or `cors` issue.

Comment: @notsodev thx for the hint the default user/password combination also doesn't work. Since the config works if the security is enabled i doubt that CORS is at the core of the problem.